# C# LINQ lambda expression with Contains as a method parameter

Tags: c#, linq, lambda, contains, func

I am writing a method that gets a lambda expression as a parameter to be used to filter the `IList<SomeModel> _collection`.

```
public void DoSomething(SomeModel model)
{
   FilterCollectionUsingPredicate(x => x.Name.Equals(model.Name));
}

private void FilterCollectionUsingPredicate(Func<SomeModel, bool> predicate)
{
   _collection = _collection.Where(predicate).ToList();
}
```

It works well when the `predicate` parameter is a simple expression, like  `x => x.Name.Equals(model.Name)`. 
However, it gets tricky when it has to use some other (local) collection and `Contains` clause.

```
public void DoSomething(SomeModel model)
{
   IEnumerable<string> someOtherCollection = model.SomeOtherCollection;
   FilterCollectionUsingPredicate(x => someOtherCollection.Contains(x.Phone));
}

private void FilterCollectionUsingPredicate(Func<SomeModel, bool> predicate)
{
   _collection = _collection.Where(predicate).ToList();
}
```

Of course, `FilterCollectionUsingPredicate` method does not see `someOtherCollection` and therefore, throws an error.
Can someone explain how to properly define and use this function to handle such a case?

Comment: What error is thrown?  FYI `someOtherCollection` will be captured as part of the lambda that is pasted.

Comment: i think ``predicate`` must be ``Expression`` not a ``Fun``.

Comment: You're going to have to add more detail, as I've attempted to reproduce this and it's working just fine.  At the very least we need to know the error.

Comment: @Sajid I doubt it because of the use of `ToList` when assigning to `_collection` would indicate we are not dealing with an `IQueryable`.  But `_collection` might be an `IEnumerable` that the OP assigns an `IQueryable` to first.  Just another reason for the OP to give more details.

Comment: @juharr: you are right, the solution in the question, it's work fine. no error.

Answer (score 0):

Well try and create a generic extension instead, Expression should keep track of all other data in the expression. Try and create the predicate as Expression

```
private void FilterCollectionUsingPredicate(Expression<Func<SomeModel, bool>> predicate)
{
   _collection = _collection.Where(predicate).ToList();
}
```

It should work.

Comment: This might be the answer, but nothing in the question implies that it is.

Comment: Func dose not keep track of all other external items, and that why your geting error. Expression keep track or path to the orginal items in the expression

Comment: @Alen.Toma That is entirely incorrect. All local variables in a lambda of type `Func<>` are captured.

Comment: You'd only need it to be an Expression if the provider is going to translate the code like EF does to translate to SQL.  If this is using Linq-to-Objects then the lambda will capture any variables used inside of it's closure.